# Integrate $\frac{x^b\ln x}{1+x}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Suppose $0<b<1$ and we are asked to evaluate $$I=\int^\infty_{0}\dfrac{x^b\ln x}{1+x}\,dx$$

Initially, I thought of using the [contour in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsAXI.png). But then the problem comes when I am trying to consider $C_R$. That is,
$$|\int_{C_R}f(z)\,dz|\leq\pi R\dfrac{R^b\ln R}{R-1}$$ but this integral does not converge to $0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$. How can I solve this question?

Edited: I also tried a keyhole contour as well but the problem remains the same. That is, $$|\int_{C_R}f(z)\,dz|\leq2\pi R\dfrac{R^b\ln R}{R-1}$$

Comment: I tried keyhole contour as well, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: The integral diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: @Alvin you really should listen to JG as he is correct, the integral doesn't converge since for $x>1$ the integrand is larger than $\frac{1}{1+x}$

Comment: The integral converges for $-1<b<0$. For $0<b$ it definitely diverges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this [AOPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h473115p2649106) it's explained that for $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+x^{\beta}}\mathrm{d}x$ to converge we require $\beta > \alpha +1 >0$. Moreover, in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457/695196) it's shown that
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}}{1+x^{\beta}}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{\beta}\csc\left(\frac{\pi(\alpha+1)}{\beta} \right)
$$
whenever the parameters $\alpha, \beta$ are in the previously stated convergence range. Now, differentiating the previous equation with respect to $\alpha$ gives
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha}\ln(x)}{1+x^{\beta}}\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{\pi^2}{\beta^2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi(\alpha+1)}{\beta} \right)\cot\left(\frac{\pi(\alpha+1)}{\beta} \right), \qquad \beta > \alpha +1 >0}
$$

---

If you're certain that the condition $0<b<1$ is correct then there was probably a mistake in the denominator (maybe it was meant to be $1+x^{\color{red}{2}}$ instead of $1+x$). Otherwise, as repeatedly pointed out in the comments, $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{b}\ln(x)}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x $ only converges for $-1<b<0$, and as such your integral (as currently stated) has no evaluation other than "Divergent".